# Pickle the python module so that after loading it I can use it normally even if there are no .py files that correspond to that module anymore

Tags: python, pickle, python-module, dill

Pickle can not dump modules at all, and dill python library can. But I was not able to figure out how I can dump it with dill so that it doesn't "ask" for having source python files that correspond to the module on my PC.

I want:

Computer 1:

```py
import my_module

import pickling_module

...
pickling_module.dump(..., my_module, ...)
...
```

Computer 2:

```py
import pickling_module

my_module = pickling_module.load(module_data)
my_module.my_func()
# And I dont want to see ModuleNotFoundError text if I dont have my_module.py file
```

Comment: It'd be probably easier to help and understand if you created a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you don't want to the see exception you can always use a `try/except` and handle the error. `try: ... except ModuleNotFoundError: ...`

Comment: Welcome to [so]. I think your question is too broad. Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically are not a good fit for this site.  Split your task into smaller ones and start working on them. And ask particular questions related to particular issues you encounter. Here's how: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)